# MacTeX-2013 didn't install TeXLive 2013

Tags: installing, texlive, mactex

I deleted my old TeXLive 2012 from my Mac (10.5.8). I downloaded the new MacTeX package and installed it successfully. TeXLive is found on directory `usr/local/texlive/2013` BUT the GUI application is not in `applications/tex`. I could run my `CV.tex` file that uses `moderncv` in TeXWorks but I would like to use the GUIapp to update packages and such.

Any ideas?

EDIT1: texhash gives me this message, I don't know if it has any significance:

texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.

Comment: The GUI application to update packages is called `TeX Live Utility.app` and can be found on directory `/Applications/TeX` or using `Finder` -> `Applications` -> `TeX`

Comment: Yeah. It's not there :( It seems like everything else is working but I cant find the TeX Live Utility.app

Comment: Do you have installed the full version (MacTeX.pkg, 2.3G) from http://tug.org/mactex/ ?

Comment: Yeah that's the one. I downloaded it from that site.

Comment: When you installed did you choose to install the Extras?

Comment: is TeX Live Utility 2013 in extras? Hmmm I did the standard install if I remember correctly. I'll have to check again, but I don't remember choosing minimal install or sth.

Comment: No it's not part of the extras package (sorry I was unclear) but there is a choice point in the installer to install the GUI parts as well.

Comment: The standard install I did should come with GUI-applications according to the installer..I only skipped the Latin-modern-Fonts and TeX-Gyre-Fonts.

Comment: Is there any terminal commands to verify proper installation?

Comment: Do you still have the installer package?  Why not just reinstall? BTW, your messages from `texhash` aren't relevant, except to show that because the TeXLive directory structure is part of the system files you need to run it using `sudo`.

Comment: I deleted the /usr/local/texlive/ and applications/tex directories as an uninstall and then did a reinstall. It didn't solve the problem. Still no TeX Live Utility.app installed.

Comment: @Jespu Please continue this discussion in a chat. And please use `@reply` to thread you comments.